# Adding Blending mode to HTML5 instance and/or shape

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, color-blending

I have made an HTML5 animation using Animate CC. The software doesn't support blending-modes for HTML5-canvases but I found this (http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/02/24/using-blend-modes-in-html-canvas/) guide how to add blending modes to an HTML5-canvas. Problem is, this adds multiple to ALL elements (shapes/instances/images) in the html-5-canvas, and I want to add id to some specific elements in my canvas.

This is from the JS generated by Animate CC, with my failed attempt to add blending mode.

```
// col-yellow
this.instance_21 = new lib.colyellow();
this.instance_21.setTransform(598.6,184.4,0.449,0.449,0,0,0,43.8,43.9
this.instance_21.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"; //my code
```

Comment: Set the globalCompositeOperation property back to source-over when you don't need it anymore?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: Well, as his name *(probably not enough clearly)* says, this property is global to the context. This does mean that every drawing operations will be affected by it (except `putImageData` which is not really a drawing operation). Its default value is `'source-over'` so if you need it for only one drawing operation, set it before this operation and reset it to `'source-over'` after. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation).